# Como compactar pasta e baixar, como proceder de uma maneira simples?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu andei fazendo bastante pesquisas tanto google, quanto fóruns e grupos de FB, mas nada do que fora explicado foi o suficiente para sanar minha duvida, creio eu que por ser novo na área e ainda estou bem "seco" pra alguns exemplos mais complexos, mas assim...

Eu preciso compactar uma pasta que é criada em um processo de busca de registros por data, compactar e baixar ela, sendo mais direto o processo é do seguinte modo, eu faço uma busca por período, ele cria uma pasta com o "período" joga os arquivos gerados dentro dela, agora eu preciso saber como prosseguir pra compactar essa pasta baixar.

A lib do php Zip eu já tenho instalada no servidor local.

O meu código atualmente está dessa maneira:

```
<?php 
$data1 = '2019-02-07';
$data2 = '2019-02-08';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=73519225000122", "root", "");
$buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT chave,conteudo FROM xml WHERE modelo = '55' AND data_gravacao BETWEEN date('$data1') AND date('$data2')");
$buscar->execute();
$buscar->bindColumn(1, $chave);
$buscar->bindColumn(2, $conteudo);
$linha = $buscar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

mkdir( $dirPath = __DIR__.'/arquivos/temp/'.$data1.'-'.$data2.'', 0777);
chmod($dirPath, 0777);

  $generated = $linha;
  foreach ($linha as $key => $value) {

        $content=$value['conteudo'];
        $fileName=$dirPath.'/'.$value['chave'].'.xml';
        $result=file_put_contents ($fileName , $content);
        if ($result===FALSE) {
          // manipula erro, lança exceção, etc...
        } else {
            $generated=$fileName; // remember this file
          }
  }
```

E sim, eu vou precisar apagar tanto a pasta quanto o zip, para que não ocupe espaço no servidor, caso o cliente deseja ter o "arquivo.zip" novamente, ele precisa executar a busca por data novamente como proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('nomeDoFicheiro.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);


$ficheiros = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($ficheiros as $nome => $ficheiro )
{

    if (!$ficheiro ->isDir())
    {

        $camihoDoFicheiro = $ficheiro ->getRealPath();
        $camihoRelativoDoFicheiro = substr($ficheiro , strlen($dirPath) + 1);

        $zip->addFile($camihoDoFicheiro , $camihoRelativoDoFicheiro);
    }
}

$zip->close();
```